# Angular JS and JSP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I have a JSP template that includes Angular code.  I need to load the variables from my model into my controller, but I can only access them from the JSP directly, not from included javascript.  Currently, I have an inline-script to load all the model information into temp variables on the JSP, and then I read them in to my controller from my Angular script.

This works fine, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to go about doing this. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725045/using-jsp-c-tag-within-angularjs-code
Appreciate if anyone can help to give the best approach to do the same.